# PHP redirect but in parent frame

Tags: php, mysql, sql, redirect, frame

I have a small time url shortner at http://thetpg.tk using a simple php script and MySQL.
What it does is to get the `id` and matches it in the SQL Database and redirects it to the specified link found in the Database using `header()`.

But if I have a frameset with source as something like `http://thetpg.tk` redirected link is loaded inside the frame instead of the parent window.

For e.g. look at the page source of

1. http://thetpgmusic.tk which has the frame source as
2. http://thetpg.tk/b which further redirects to
3. http://thepirategamer.tk/music.php .

I want (1) to load (3) as the parent, but just by making changes in the functions in (2) .
So is there a function like

`header(Location:http://thepirategamer.tk/music.php, '_parent');`
in php, or is there any other way to implement it?

NOTE: I can't change anything in (2).

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: `_parent` / `target=".."` is clientside, PHP serverside.

Comment: what about using javascript, php functions are clientside and there is no function like you want.

Comment: In html there's an attribute used in the `<a>` tag 

`target="_parent"`

Isn't there something like that for the header or any other function built in php?

Comment: But can I use JavaScript to fetch php variables?
Or should is use `echo` in php to write JavaScript?
I have seen a JavaScript solution, but I would like to achieve it with php instead.

Answer (score 4):

There are tree solutions that can help you do this:

---

## First solution:

This solution may involve php if you're using `echo` to generate your html code, when you need to output an `a` tag, you should make sure to add the atribute `target='_parent'`

```
<?php
        echo '<a href="' . $url . '" target="_parent"> Click here </a>';
?>
```

#### problem :

The problem with this solution, is that it doesn't work if you need to redirect in the parent window from a page that you don't own (inside the iframe). The second solution solves this problem

---

## Second solution:

This second solution is totally client-side, wich means you need to use some javascript. you should define a javascript function that addes the `target='_parent'` in every `a` tag

```
function init ()  
{
      TagNames = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      for( var x=0; x < TagNames.length; x++ )
            TagNames[x].onclick = function()
            { 
                   this.setAttribute('target','_parent'); 
            }
};
```

Now all you need to do is to call this function when the body is loaded like this

```
<body onload="init();"> ... </body>
```

#### problem:

The problem with this solution, is that if you have a link that contains an anchor like this `href="#"` it will change the parent window to the child window To solve this problem, you have to use the third solution

---

## Third solution:

This solution is also client-side and you have to use javascript. It is like the second solution except that you have to test if the link is a url to an external page or to an anchor before you redirect. so you need to define a function that returns true if it's a link to an external page and false if it's a simple anchor, and then you'll have to use this function like this

```
function init ()  
{
      TagNames = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      for( var x=0; x < TagNames.length; x++ )
            TagNames[x].onclick = function()
            { 
                   if ( is_external_url( this.href ) )
                       document.location = this.href;
            }
};
```

and you also need to call this function when the body is loaded

```
<body onload="init();"> ... </body>
```

don't forget to define `is_external_url()`

---

---

## update :

Here is the solution to get the url of the last child, it's just a simple function that looks from frames and iframes inside the paages and get the urls

```
function get_last_url($url)
{
    $code = file_get_contents($url);
    $start = strpos($code, '<frameset');
    $end = strpos($code, '</frameset>');
    if($start===false||$end===false)
    {
        $start = strpos($code, '<iframe');
        $end = strpos($code, '</iframe>');
        if($start===false||$end===false)
            return $url;
    }
    $sub = substr($code, $start,$end-$start);
    $sub = substr($sub, strpos($sub,'src="')+5);
    $url = explode('"', $sub)[0];
    return get_last_child($url);
}

$url = get_last_url("http://thetpgmusic.tk/");
header('Location: ' . $url);
exit();
```

Comment: I am not using an `<a>` tag to redirect. I am not even showing the link to the page which will be loaded.
I am simply redirecting. So no `<a>` tags please.
So, could you elaborate on the 'redirecting' part rather than the `<a>` part?

Comment: sorry, now I understood exactly what you need, I'll work on it right now, I have a php solution and a javascript solution, do you need both of them or just one ?

Comment: PHP would be better, but both are appreciated. :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KunalGupta , the javascript solution is not a good one, here is the php solution in my post update

Comment: @KunalGupta It's good practice to always follow a redirect header tag with an `exit();` statement.

Comment: @Arian, I updated the post, I followed the header with `exit();`. thank you :)